# Obtener texto de una base de datos en html Angular

Tags: php, sql, angular

Tengo un texto guardado en mi base de datos, en un campo tipo TEXT la cuestión es que tengo unas estiquetas `<br>` y al sacar la información.

```
{{descripcion}}
```

Me saca todo en formato texto, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el problema puede que venga del **`SELECT`** a la base de datos, el cual es el siguiente:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM home;";
$query = $db->query($sql);

$result = array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'code' => 401,
    'message' => 'Usuario no encontrado'
);

if($query->num_rows == 1){
    $home = $query->fetch_assoc();

    $result = array(
        'status' => 'succes',
        'code' => 200,
        'data' => $home
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

La base de datos es MySQL, muchas gracias!

Comment: donde quiere cambiar el texto, en la db o solo en la presentacion en {{descripcion}} ?

Comment: Quiero que al mostrar el texto en {{descripcion}} el html se convierta a html por ejemplo si tengo un <br> que al mostrar {{descripcion}} ver un salto de línea. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: revisa esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300100/convert-text-to-html-format-in-angular

Comment: no consigo aplicarli :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar algo como esto

```
<div [innerHTML]="description"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres sacar las etiquetas HTML podrias utilizar https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text

```
// when installed using the Composer package
$text = Html2Text\Html2Text::convert($html);

// usage when installed using html2text.php
require('html2text.php');
$text = convert_html_to_text($html);
```

Comment: Eso debería meterlo en la API?

Comment: Como lo desees, si quieres puedes incluir solamente la clase html2text.php , o usar el composer package .

Answer (score 0):

si deseas pintarlo directamente en el html, usa la etiqueta ng-bind-html = "espacioTrush( descripcion)" , desde tu controlador de angular transforma la variable usando lo siguiente

`vm.espacioTrush = function(cadena) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(cadena);
}`

Answer (score -1):

Usa html_entity_decode

```
echo json_encode($result);
echo html_entity_decode(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: Además de publicar código, deberías explicar por qué crees que el código responde la pregunta.